# Changing group icon in legend with Python in QGIS 2.6?

Tags: pyqgis, legend, icon

How to change the group icon in legend via Python in QGIS 2.6?

At version 1.x I did it this way:

```py
self.legendTree = self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget,"Legend").findChild(QTreeWidget)
currGrp=self.legendTree.currentItem()
currGrp.setIcon(0,self.setMyIcon("folder.png")
```

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: I would want that group created by plugin differs from the group created by man. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Edit

A bit of self-promotion here: I developed a QGIS plugin to solve this exact issue.

[Layer Tree Icons](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/layertreeicons/)

It can be installed from the QGIS Plugin manager, and it's pretty straightforward to use

[image: LayerTreeIcons]

The plugin adds two actions in the layer tree context menu, to set a custom icon on a single node:

- **Set icon from file**: Browse the computer to set the node icon from an image file
- **Set icon from QGIS resources**: Open a Resource Browser to use one of the icons embedded in QGIS

[image: Resource browser]

It also adds a small configuration dialog (accessible from the new button in the layer tree toolbar), to change the icon size for the whole tree, and to change the default icons (group icon, mesh layer icon, etc...)

[image: Settings Menu]

**PyQGIS Cookbook**

- Set custom icon for a specific node:

```
iface.layerTreeView().currentNode().setCustomProperty(
    "plugins/customTreeIcon/icon", 
    "path/to/icon.png"
)
```

- Set custom icon for an icon type:

```
# Group
QSettings().setValue("plugins/layertreeicons/defaulticons/group", "path/to/icon.png")
# Raster
QSettings().setValue("plugins/layertreeicons/defaulticons/raster", "path/to/icon.png")
# Point
QSettings().setValue("plugins/layertreeicons/defaulticons/point", "path/to/icon.png")
# Line
QSettings().setValue("plugins/layertreeicons/defaulticons/line", "path/to/icon.png")
# Polygon
QSettings().setValue("plugins/layertreeicons/defaulticons/polygon", "path/to/icon.png")
# No Geometry
QSettings().setValue("plugins/layertreeicons/defaulticons/nogeometry", "path/to/icon.png")
# Mesh
QSettings().setValue("plugins/layertreeicons/defaulticons/mesh", "path/to/icon.png")
```

If you're interested in tweaking the layer tree yourself, see the original answer below.

---

## Original answer

In QGIS2 as well as in QGIS3, the group icon is set by the `QgsLayerTreeModel`, in its `data` method.

From QGIS source code ([QGIS 2.18](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/qgslayertreemodel_8cpp_source.html#l00184), [QGIS 3.10](https://qgis.org/api/qgslayertreemodel_8cpp_source.html#l00157)):

```
QVariant QgsLayerTreeModel::data( const QModelIndex &index, int role ) const
{
   if ( !index.isValid() || index.column() > 1 )
     return QVariant();
   ...
   
   if ( role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole )
   {
     ...
   }
   else if ( role == Qt::DecorationRole && index.column() == 0 )
   {
     if ( QgsLayerTree::isGroup( node ) )
       return iconGroup();
     ...
   }
   ...
}
```

The `iconGroup` function returns a static theme icon. While it is possible to override these icons, it is not possible to have a custom icon per group whith this implementation.

---

Fortunately, it is fairly easy to extend `QgsLayerTreeModel` using PyQt to get the desired behavior.

```
class CustomLayerModel(QgsLayerTreeModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomLayerModel, self).__init__(QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot(), parent)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        node = self.index2node(index)
        if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            if QgsLayerTree.isGroup(node):
                if node.customProperty("legend/icon"):
                    return QIcon(node.customProperty("legend/icon"))
        return super(CustomLayerModel, self).data(index, role)
```

This `CustomLayerModel` will behave exactly like the classic `QgsLayerTreeModel`, but for group nodes, it will check whether a custom property (arbitrarily called "legend/icon") exists, and return a custom `QIcon` accordingly.

The model of the QGIS layer tree view must now be replaced by our custom one.

```
def replace_original_model():
    model = CustomLayerModel()
    # Keep a reference to the model so it does not get garbage collected
    iface.custom_model = model
    # Save the original model 
    if not hasattr(iface, 'original_model'):
        iface.original_model = iface.layerTreeView().layerTreeModel()
    # Copy the flags used by the original model
    model.setFlags(iface.original_model.flags())
    # Replace the original model
    iface.layerTreeView().setModel(model)
```

We can also define another helper function, which restores the orignal model if needed

```
def restore_original_model():
    if hasattr(iface, 'original_model'):
        iface.layerTreeView().setModel(iface.original_model)
```

One last thing to do: define a helper function which will set the icon for a given group

```
def set_group_icon(group_name, icon_url):
    group = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup(group_name)
    if group:
        # Write custom property
        group.setCustomProperty("legend/icon", icon_url)
        # Trigger refresh
        index = iface.layerTreeView().layerTreeModel().node2index(group)
        iface.layerTreeView().layerTreeModel().dataChanged.emit(index, index)
```

**Usage:**

```
>>> replace_original_model()
>>> set_group_icon("group1", "path/to/my/icon.svg")
```